# Add class to parent if all childeren have class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, addclass

So I'm creating a progress bar, but I'm running into a little problem.
The rule I'm trying to implement:

for each `li.page` check if `li.question = li.question.done`, if true `.addClass` `.done` to this

So in the HTML below, #p1 should have class done, #p2 and #p3 shouldn't.

The current JS results in adding class `.done` to all `.page` li's in the page if one `.page` has all questions done.

Hope someone can help me get this to work, all help is appreciated!

This is the html:

```
<ul class="pages">
    <li id="p1" class="page">
        <ul class="questions">
            <li id="q2" class="question done">1</li>
            <li id="q3" class="question done">2</li>
            <li id="q4" class="question done">3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="p2" class="page">
        <ul class="questions">
            <li id="q5" class="question current">4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="p3" class="page">
        <ul class="questions">
            <li id="q6" class="question done">5</li>
            <li id="q7" class="question">6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>           
</ul>
```

And this JS:

```
var doneCheck = function(){
    $(".page").each(function () {
        questionsInPage = $(this).closest(".questions").find("li").length;
        questionsDone = $(this).closest(".questions").find("li.done").length;

        var done = questionsDone == questionsInPage;

        $(".page").each(function() {
            if (done) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('done');
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `.closest` looks for a parent, but `.questions` is a child of `.page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `page` I would check the number of `li` against the number of elements with class question and done. If they match set page to done.

```js
var doneCheck = function() {
  $(".page").each(function() {
    if($('.question.done', this).length==$('ul li',this).length)
      $(this).addClass('done');
  });
}
doneCheck();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pages">
  <li id="p1" class="page">
    <ul class="questions">
      <li id="q2" class="question done">1</li>
      <li id="q3" class="question done">2</li>
      <li id="q4" class="question done">3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="p2" class="page">
    <ul class="questions">
      <li id="q5" class="question current">4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="p3" class="page">
    <ul class="questions">
      <li id="q6" class="question done">5</li>
      <li id="q7" class="question">6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding all the done questions, count the number of *not* done questions. If it's zero, all the questions are done. Use this to set the `done` property of the page.

```js
function doneCheck() {
  $(".page").each(function() {
    var allDone = $(this).find(".questions li.question:not(.done)").length == 0;
    $(this).toggleClass("done", allDone);
  });
}

$("#check").click(doneCheck);
```

```css
.page.done {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pages">
  <li id="p1" class="page">
    <ul class="questions">
      <li id="q2" class="question done">1</li>
      <li id="q3" class="question done">2</li>
      <li id="q4" class="question done">3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="p2" class="page">
    <ul class="questions">
      <li id="q5" class="question current">4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="p3" class="page">
    <ul class="questions">
      <li id="q6" class="question done">5</li>
      <li id="q7" class="question">6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

FYI, you can't use `==` to compare the results of two selectors. If you want to test whether they're equivalent, use `.is`:

```
if (questionsDone.is(questionsInPage)
```

But your second loop is wrong, because it sets the class on *all* `.page` elements based on the `done` status of the current page of the loop.